# Create Trigger to watch document value mongoDB to send email

Tags: javascript, mongodb, triggers, document, watch

I am kind of new to MongoDB and web development in general, so this might be an easy one for you. I want to send out emails based on the time difference of the current time and the event time. The event time is in the event model saved as a standard attribute.

`eventDate: Date` JavaScript date object

What is the best approach to that. Ideally I would define some sort of watcher comparing the current time with the event time, I am not sure though. I appreciate any kind of guidance.

Best,
Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has no embedded triggers, so you can write your own service for periodic value checking. For example you can use Node.js with `periodic-task` module for such a job.